# Use Taylor Theorem to find the polynomial approximation

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

A) Find a polynomial approximation for $f(x)=2e^x$ centered at $0$ for values of $x$ in the interval $[-1,1]$

B) what is the actual bound on the error in your approximation given by Taylor theorem?

Hello, I have no clue on how to even start problems like this, assistance is appreciated.

Comment: What does Taylor's Theorem say first of all?

Answer (score 0):

The taylor series formula around $0$ is: $$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty f^n(0)\frac{x^n}{n!}$$
For $e^x$, computing each derivative is $1$ so:$$2e^x=2\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$$.

Using [Remainder Estimation Theorem](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~mklipper/2260/F14/taylorerror.pdf): $$|R_{n}(x)|\le \frac{M|x|^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$$ Where $M$ is the maximum value of $f^{n+1}(x)$ on the interval. We know that that is just $2e$, so $$|R_{n}(x)|\le \frac{2e|x|^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$$